# Change field "updateable" status

Tags: fields, field-update

My company uses webhooks to create orders & order items in our Salesforce instance from our Shopify store.

When an order is updated if an extra product is added to that Shopify order it is added properly as an extra `OrderItem` in Salesforce but when it is updated it throws an error.

```
[
    {
        "errorCode": "APEX_ERROR",
        "message": "System.DmlException: Upsert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: INVALID_FIELD_FOR_INSERT_UPDATE, Unable to create/update fields: PricebookEntryId.
        Please check the security settings of this field and verify that it is read/write for your profile or permission set.: [PricebookEntryId]
        Class.shopifyOrderUpdateEventListener.doPost: line 292, column 1"
    }
]
```

This is the code which updates the OrderItem

```
for(shopifyOrderJSON.cls_line_items i:helper.line_items){
    if(m.containsKey(i.SKU)) {
        OrderItem ol= new OrderItem();
        ol.OrderId = o.id;
        ol.PricebookEntryId = m.get(i.SKU).Id;
        ol.Quantity = i.quantity;
        ol.UnitPrice = Decimal.valueOf(i.price);
        ol.Description = i.name;
        ol.Service__c = i.fulfillment_service;
        ol.Grams__c = i.grams;
        ol.Order_Line_ID__c = shopifyOrg + String.valueOf(i.id);
        ol.Requires_Shipping__c = i.requires_shipping;
        lines.add(ol);
    }
}
```

The issue is most likely due to the fact that the `PricebookEntryId` field on `OrderItem` is createable but not updateable.
I have verified this through an API call to the `/describe` value of `OrderItem`.

The problem is that the field doesn't show up in the Object Manager for `OrderItem` so that I can set it to updateable too.

[image]

Has anyone encountered this issue before?
Ideally any suggestions on fixing this / making the field updateable too?

Cheers.

Comment: It looks like the field value **is changing**. Meaning you didn't link your order line to the correct item. Check your code's behavior to make sure you're setting the correct value. My answer was based on the thought that you were getting a compilation error, but I've confirmed that the error only triggers if you actually do try to change the PricebookEntryId to a different value.