# Order Product Object Change Non Updateable Fields

Tags: upsert

I found an older question which is similar use case that I am facing [HERE](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/198501/change-field-updateable-status). I would have just commented on that thread but I do not have enough rep points.  Thank you!

Is there a way to change a updateable : false to true?  This just helps me with my upserts if I can change it to updateable.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks.  Well that is really the answer i was looking for if the attribute can be changed.  Ill leave out the "why" I want to change it to simplify my question next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, you cannot change most of the behaviors of standard fields, including allowing reparenting of master-detail fields, such as the OrderId field on OrderLineItem. There are a few exceptions, like changing the auto-number format of standard auto-number fields, but these are rare exceptions to the rule.